# HQL query takes way too long to execute

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have this HQL query:

```
String hql = "from "+Patient.class.getName() + " p "
                + " where p.medicalRoom.id = "+medicalRoom.getId()
                + " and exists (select tg.id  from "+TherapyGroup.class.getName()+" tg where tg.treatment.patient.id = p.id "
                + " and not exists (select ta.id from "+TherapyEnd.class.getName()+" ta where ta.therapyGroup.id = tg.id))";
```

All the properties that are involved in the query are indexed... Though it takes more than one whole minute to execute..

Comment: Sooo... What have you tried? Have you at least logged out the actual SQL that hibernate executes?

Comment: the actual query, number of records and you're using exists and not exists with 2 sub-selects.. you could try running the generated query in the db directly and see the query plan that the db employs and see where the bulk of the time is getting spent. are you sure it's the query and the 1 minute is not end-to-end from UI to db to UI?

Comment: I have run the query in the db directly and it takes the same amount of time, depending on the "medicalRoom.getId()" value, it ranges from 18 sec to 120+ sec... the generated query has nothing special, it is what it is supposed to be... So it is not end-to-end from UI to DB to UI which takes soooo long, but the actual query is consuming a lot of time :S